# Compilation of llvm and clang from their git repos hangs at 96%

Tags: compilation, clang, llvm

I have a problems with compilation of llvm and clang with bpf and x86 targets on debian machine. GCC version is 6.2,python exists on system.Compilation lasts more than 24 hours already.Now it hangs at 
96% linking cxx executable ../../bin/opt

What to wait more or to do with this?

Comment: Try running `strace` on the hanging process to see if you can figure out where it hangs. Or try attaching `gdb`?

Comment: or even simply look and see if it's using any CPU with top.

Comment: At that moment I couldn't had even open second tty with ctrl-alt-f2.It hadn't been responding.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably your linker is running out of RAM. Few suggestions:

- Release builds tend to require less RAM for linking compared to Debug one
- Use gold, not bfd ld
- Add more RAM :)

Comment: You can also use -gsplit-dwarf to help link time as well. Requires a fairly new gdb to debug after though.